# How can i call a thing a lot of times (game: dodger)

Tags: javascript, game-mechanics

Hey I am new to coding and i want to know how to get the same thing to hapen until i "say" stop.

The game is that you need to dodge stuff that is falling, i was thinking that i could use a while loop and Push the object in the list like the following:

```
Var i = 0;
Var theObjects = [ ];
While ( i < 100)
{
    theObjects.push();
    i ++;
}
```

But that would be 1. Spawn them at the same time and the it would be 2. This only works for x amount of time.

How can i make the object spawn til i say stop and spawn at difrent times

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I edited your question to make it clear. Please take a look to verify if that is closer to what you were trying to convey. Also, let me ask you: what you want is a way to make the while not dependent on how many times `theObjects.push()` was called, but actually dependent on some other external factor that you choose?

Comment: Yeah, so like random cubes are falling and when they hitt the player they stop falling, so you have to dodge the cubes. I want them to fall random not at the same time, i get that with the list thing

Comment: Thanks for the info. Are you running your `while-loop` inside the main game loop (the one that circles trough game frames)?

Comment: I have not started with the code but i thougt about the problem, i am not going to have fancy grafics or somthing. I am doing this for like a programing course, it like realy basic stuff. This is the programing thing we are using http://koda.nu/labbet/3742937 , i don't know if what i am doing is to complicated for me, but i thought it would be cool

Comment: I posted an answer before reading your last comment above, and now looking your code in more detail, it seems that I was right in the suspicion I mentioned in my answer: you are using the while-loop inside the update() function. I will update my answer with a more concrete example that tackles your specific engine case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can i make the object spawn til i say stop and spawn at difrent times

You have two different questions there. One is how you can make the object spawn until you say it to stop. The other is how to spawn them at different times.

It is not very clear to me what you exactly mean regarding the first part. If you just wanna learn how to make a "while loop" that does run infinitely until you say it to stop, then this can be easily achieved with a minor change in your while loop code. For instance:

```
Var stopwhile = false;
Var theObjects = [ ];
While ( stopwhile == false)
{
    theObjects.push();

    //here you include your own code to test when stopwhile should be set to true, which will then make the while-loop stop
}
```

However, I have a suspicion that you might be making a confusion. If you are running your while-loop inside your general main game loop (the one that re-starts after each frame ends and is usually a function called "Update()" or "main()"), then there is your problem.

The main game loop (or the update() function) loops trough frames. It means, each game frame is an iteration of the loop. It means that if you put your while-loop inside the main loop, then each frame will only end after the whole while-loop runs. Consequently, every frame all spawning will happen in the same frame, giving the impression that they happened at the same time.

If that is the case, then you have to abandon the while-loop approach altogether. The simpler way to do it is to just create a function that does whatever you intend to, for example spawn balls and call it inside the main game loop after a given amount of time has passed:

```
var repeat_the_code = true;
var timecounter = 0;
var spawn_delay = 50; // or the value you prefer
var max_spawn_delay = 100; // or the value you prefer

function Spawn() {
    //here you put the code you want to repeat, like the `theObjects.push();` in your original example
    timecounter = 0; // you reset the counter every time a new spawn is generated
    spawn_delay = Math.random(max_spawn_delay); //when each spawn is finished, you randomly set how much delay you desire before the next spawn
}

Update(){  //or the name it may have in your engine, but basically it is the function that repeats throughout the game, with each game frame being its iterations

  if(repeat_the_code && timecounter == spawn_delay) { //if the timer has reached the desired delay value AND the trigger repeat_the_code is still set to 'true', then a new spawn occurs by calling the corespondent function:
          Spawn(); //this is how you call the spawn function that you defined before
  }        
}
```

That way, you will both be able to stop spawning whenever you want (just create a condition that sets `repeat_the_code = false`) and also to spawn at randomly different amounts of time.

EDIT: as for a more concrete example, using your engine framework something like the following might work:

```
  var max_bollar = 10;
  var i = 0;
  var timecounter = 0;
  var bollarcounter = 0;
  var spawn_delay = 200;
  var min_spawn_delay = 25;
  var max_spawn_delay = 500;

  function spawn(i)
  {
  var boll = {x: random(totalWidth), y: random(totalHeight)}
  circle( boll.x, 10, 10, "blue");
  timecounter = 0;
  bollarcounter++;
  max_spawn_delay = ( random(max_spawn_delay - min_spawn_delay ) + min_spawn_delay );
  }

  function update()
  {
    timecounter += 1;
    if(timecounter == spawn_delay && bollarcounter < max_bollar) spawn(bollarcounter);
  }
```

Comment: @Samuel you are mostly welcome! Please consider marking the answer as accepted if it helped you solving the issue.

Comment: @Samuel Not necessary! But just to help you learn about the site, let me tell you that to accept an answer, you have to click on that "acceptance button", like the following: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

This will execute the same function every 2 seconds change the delay to change how often the function is called and set carryOn to false to stop calling the function every "delay" number of milliseconds ...

```
var delay = 2000;
var maxDelay = 4000;
var carryOn = true;
setTimeout(stuffToDo, delay);

function stuffToDo() {
  //whatever code you want here
  DoPart1();
  DoPart2();

  if(carryOn) { 
      delay = Math.round(Math.random() * maxDelay);
      setTimeout(stuffToDo, delay); 
  }
}

function DoPart1() { ... }

function DoPart2() { ... }
```

Comment: Can i do like var delay = random( 3000, 4000)? And can you have a function in a function, i am new to coding. Or do the time thing efect the stuff on top of it in the function?

Comment: yeh you can do both ... might be worth spending some time reading up on javascript fundamentals

Comment: I added a bit more to the code to help get you started (covers functions inside functions and random numbers ... there's also some great documentation here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_math.asp

Comment: var bollar = [ ];
  var i = 0;
  
  while( i < 10)
  {
    bollar.push({x: random(totalWidth), y: random(totalHeight)});
      i ++;       
  }
  
  function update()
  {
    var i = 0;
    
    while( i < 10)
    {
      var boll = bollar[i];
      circle( boll.x, boll.y, 10, "blue");
      i ++;
    }
  }

Comment: So IF i want the bollar = balls and boll = ball to apear in diffrent times how do i do that, sorry if i am anoying

Comment: @Samuel one thing for me to better understand you. Regarding your last comments to this answer, why do you still wanna use the `while` loop after Wardy's answer?

Comment: I did not realy understand how to get the "cubes" in it Without the while one

Comment: @Samuel the current answer means that we have a function that automatically sets itself up to run every random number of milliseconds, the idea being that in that function or one of its child functions you could spawn your "cubes" ... this is basically doing a while loop as well but instead of instantly executing each iteration it executes each iteration after a random delay.